# Inverse limit of compact hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, limits-colimits

Suppose that $(X,\varphi_i)$ is an inverse limit of an inverse system of compact hausdorff spaces $\{X_i,\varphi_{ij}\}$. Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$, I would like to proof that $\overline{Y}$ (closure in X) is the inverse limit of $\{\varphi_i(Y),\varphi_{ij}\}$. Since $\varphi_i:Y\rightarrow \varphi_i(Y)$ is onto, the image of the inclusion $Y\rightarrow \text{lim} \ \varphi_i(Y)$ is dense. The problem is that I don't know how to show that $\text{lim} \ \varphi_i(Y)$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t true. Consider an extremely simple directed system with only one object, with the unique $\phi$ simply being the identity map. Then applying your claim to this system, we get that every subset of every compact Hausdorff space is closed, which is clearly false.

Comment: Yes, with your example it is clearly false. Thanks. But it means that $\overline{Y}$ is not necessarily the limit of $\varphi_i(Y)$. I have read this proposal in Profinite Groups by Luis Ribes (page 7), it is strange. ( I already know that it s true if $Y$ is closed)